# Give hand icon and tooltip for the hightlighted words in a sentence flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

My requirement is to change the color of some words in a sentence and give hand icon and also show a tooltip with some actions.

Like this,

[image]

I used `highlight_text: ^1.6.0`.But I am facing two issues,

1)not able to add hand icon to that highlighted text

2)not able to give tooltips with some actions

Answer (score 0):

SelectableText() widget may helps you for select text with cut ,copy /paste action , for more info explain briefly with some code snippets